# Wait Time for BlackBerry App World Vendor Registration

Tags: blackberry, vendor

i registered as vendor on BlackBerry App World. I received a mail and that mail told me that i must send another mail to another address with a national identity document. I sent it 24 hours ago. I still didn't have an answer.

How much time can it take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical wait time for **BlackBerry App World** registration is **under 48 hours.** It can take up to a week or so though depending on how busy they are or how accurate your application is.

Specifically BlackBerry state:

> Once you have submitted your documentation, **please allow 24-48 hours**
>   for it to be processed. You will receive an email from BlackBerry App
>   World confirming your vendor account has been approved.